# Selenium: Invalid cookie domain exception for subdomains

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I try to write UI-tests with Selenium based with C#. If I run the test for www domains e.g [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), I can set the cookie. If the domain has another subdomain like test.example.com, then the exception InvalidCookieDomainException is raised.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can solve the problem?

```
    private static void IsWorking()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try {
            // Navigate to Url
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.example.com");

            // Adds the cookie into current browser context
            driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie("key", "value"));
        } finally {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
    private static void IsNotWorking()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try {
            // Navigate to Url
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test.example.com");

            // Adds the cookie into current browser context
            driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie("key", "value"));
        } finally {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add cookies in [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) firstly, then navigate to test.example.com

```
    private static void IsWorking()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try {
            // Navigate to Url
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.example.com");

            // Adds the cookie into current browser context
            driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie("key", "value"));
            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test.example.com");
        } finally {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it out, but it wont work. In the developer tools of Chrome browser, is no cookie for test.example.com set, but when I go back in browser to pre-page www.example.com, is the written cookie there.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I found a solution after reading the RFC6265 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265 documentation. The trick is to first open the root or www domain and then set the coopkie for .example.com. The dot before the root domain ensures that the cookie applies to all subdomains.

The following code is working for me.

```
    private static void IsWorkingNow()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try {
            // Navigate to Url
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.example.com");

            // Adds the cookie into current browser context
            driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie("key", "value", ".example.com", "/", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)));
            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test.example.com");
        } finally {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
```